# Do badges benefit you at all?

Tags: support, badges

Hello I am relatively to Stack Exchange and I was wondering what are badges for? Do they give you privileges reputation, or are they just another thing to get more of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Steve pointed out badges are more or less for fun and bragging only. There is however one opportunity where certain badges might carry *some* weight, and that is moderator elections. While the candidates should make their point beside reputation and badges, e.g. by means of the questionaire, some badges relavant to moderation are listed during the election period too. For those voters who don't want to read all the stuff, rep and badges might be some kind of a guide. (Again, *some* it is, or at least that is what I hope. It should not be about the numbers only.)

So of you intend to run for moderator in the future, collect some badges that show you're also up to the house keeping work that comes with it, e.g. voting, flagging, editing.

Here's how [the candidate score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252641/what-are-the-details-on-the-candidate-score-which-shows-during-an-election) is calculated.

Comment: That's true, the election guide thingy gives each candidate a score out of 40 points. If I recall correctly, 20-30 points of that are for badges.

Comment: @Jacobm001, now that you mention it. There's also a calculator for that. I used it when Worldbuilding had its election to see that I have like 2 points over there.

Comment: I just cannot find it, but here's at least a meta post explaining how badges count: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252641/what-are-the-details-on-the-candidate-score-which-shows-during-an-election

Comment: Thanks Ghanima good answer! Obviously I won't run for moderator anytime soon:)

Comment: Don't we have to kill a current moderator to force an election ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Badges do not grant you privilege. Privileges are tied to reputation. Badges are however, part of the gamification of all the stackexchange sites. So they carry bragging rights only. Most questions about reputation, privileges and badges can be answered by reading the site's [help documentation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: There's even a secret badge for "most bragging, least rights" which can only be held by [one person at a time](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/8496/jacobm001?tab=profile).

Comment: @goldilocks: is this a bronze, silver, or gold badge? And do I have this badge in meta, or the main site? :P

Comment: @Jacobm001  It's a lifetime achievement (platinum/neodymium alloy) and counts across the board ;P

Comment: @goldilocks: So then, I'm the only person who will ever get this badge? Awesome! ;)

Comment: You know I am only teasing.  It's because of all the jokes Ghanima keeps making about you in the "Mod chat" room.   Keeps Steve and I in stitches.