# Why have I not Gained Reputation

Tags: discussion

On this meta site I have two questions, [one](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/788/how-to-discuss-on-meta) with 5 Votes and [one](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/762/do-badges-benefit-you-at-all) with 4 Votes I do not think I have gained reputation from getting upvoted. Is there a rule that you cannot make reputation with upvotes on questions on meta or what?

Comment: Having looked at your activity on the main site and the number of deleted posts I would suggest that you read the FAQ http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help and take the tour http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour. Reputation will come automatically from solid community participation.

Comment: You have no answers or questions on the main site. As Steve said, you don't gain or lose reputation on meta, which is a **good** thing. Make sure to participate on the main site, and you'll gain reputation over time.

Comment: @Steve Robillard It seems that Stack exchange in general is unfriendly to first time users. It basically cannot be used for someone to quickly have a question answered. Only those that spend more time asking a question than actually figuring it out themselves will gain reputation. And succeed on a Stack exchange site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot earn reputation on meta. For more [detail](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250888/reputation-in-stackoverflow-meta) on this check this out.